# Inserting Multipolygons to MongoDB writes nulls instead of coordinates (on Meteor 1.1.0.2)

Tags: mongodb, meteor, geojson

I'm trying to write GEOJSON Multipolygon objects into Mongo on my Meteor app.

The object contains several such objects:

```
var myPolygons = [ {"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[34.826198,32.063821],[34.82618,32.063779],[34.824903,32.063947],[34.820535,32.064516],
...
[34.826329,32.06418],[34.826272,32.064019],[34.826217,32.06387],[34.826198,32.063821]]]]},"properties":{"cartodb_id":12,"category":"someCategory","name":"Some Name"}} ]
```

The multipolygons are passing (=drawing correctly) on http://geojsonlint.com/

Using find() on my db shows items were inserted, but they contain null instead of coordinates, like so:

```
{ "_id" : "9mraZmupTY5ZRN2BD", "type" : "Feature", "geometry" : { "type" : "MultiPolygon", "coordinates" : [ [ [ null, null, null, null ] ], [ [ null, null, null, null ] ], [ [ null, null, null, null ] ] ] }, "properties" : { "cartodb_id" : 12, "category" : "someCategory", "name" : "Some Name" } }
```

I'm using a simple insert, nothing special:

```
_(myPolygons).each(function (item) {
  SomeDB.insert(item);
});
```

Why is this happening? Is there a MongoDB nesting limitation I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with GeoJSON. The problem was that i was copying the Multipolygon from a textfile and trying to create an Array.

Instead this worked for me

```
var state = JSON.parse(Assets.getText('states.txt')); // state.txt is a file in 'private folder' of meteor
    //  console.log(JSON.stringify(state));
    if (State.find({}).count() < 1) {  // Checking if 
        _.each(state.features, function (s) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(s));
            var a = new Object();
            a.loc = s.geometry; // am storing in LOC so that i can do a geoSpatial Index on this Field
            State.insert(a); // State is My Collection
        })
    }
```

Please Note that this code is running on the server. 
I have not tried inserting the data from the client.

Hope this helps